# Changing the default style for ggplot

Tags: python, ggplot2, styles, decorator

I wrote the following decorative function to change the default style for ggplot to be called for each plotting task:

```
# Style plots (decorator)
def plot_styling(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        style = {'axes.titlesize' : 24,
                'axes.labelsize' : 20,
                'lines.linewidth' : 3,
                'lines.markersize' : 10,
                'xtick.labelsize' : 16,
                'ytick.labelsize' : 16,
                }
        with plt.style.context((style)):
            ax = func(*args, **kwargs)      
    return wrapper
```

Now, I want to change the default grid color from light grey to white and the grid lines to gray. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking over the reference document [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html) there are the following that you can change that would achieve what you want:

- `panel.background`
- `panel.grid.major`
- `panel.grid.minor`

There reference implies we assign the value of these attributes to a value returned from an [`element_`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/element.html) function.

> **`panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50")`**
>   [image: Image from reference documents to set the background of a grid to white]

To modify your decorator, I would add these into the `style` dictionary.

```
# Style plots (decorator)
def plot_styling(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        style = {'axes.titlesize': 24,
                 'axes.labelsize': 20,
                 'lines.linewidth': 3,
                 'lines.markersize': 10,
                 'xtick.labelsize': 16,
                 'ytick.labelsize': 16,
                 'panel.background': element_rect(fill="white"),
                 'panel.grid.major': element_line(colour="grey50"),
                 'panel.grid.minor': element_line(colour="grey50")
                }
        with plt.style.context((style)):
            ax = func(*args, **kwargs)      
    return wrapper
```